# Fast search, no tokenization

Tags: java, mongodb, lucene

I'm looking for a way to do a fast full text search of a million 1-kilobyte strings.

The popular ways of speeding up this sort of thing (Lucene, or a text index in MongoDB) seem to derive their high performance at searching time from the splitting up of the content strings into tokens that they do at index-building time.  These tokens are based on natural language words.  However I would like to avoid this kind of tokenization because I want to search for strings that have nothing to do with natural language words.

I am looking for something similar in functionality to an SQL "LIKE '%abc%'", but not just "abc".  Say, for a string such as "a.1", and have that match a document such as "..........a.123........"

I get the impression that theoretically, this is possible using [suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) but I haven't found an appropriate Java implementation of these.  By "appropriate" I mean one that doesn't rely on the entire suffix tree being loaded into memory at once.

Has this been invented yet?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

> By "appropriate" I mean one that doesn't rely on the entire suffix tree being loaded into memory at once.

As far as I know and understand suffix trees there is no way to load just part of suffix tree and use it. You can ovoid this by using an algorithm, like Aho-Corasick or Boyer-Moore algorithm as mentioned @fge.

The one of realization, must poppular is:
https://github.com/abahgat/suffixtree

Also there is good and simple alghorithm to find a substring in string:
[Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)
which is well laid out in "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" for example
This algothm is used in antiviruses for searching a virus signature in virus db, and in DNA processing which is very impressive.